# VBA or Excel formula for random 10 digits numbers generator

Tags: excel, vba, random, excel-formula

My goal is to generate 10-digit random numbers and divisible by 9. Can be solved this via excel formula or VBA ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use this formula:

```
=RANDBETWEEN(1000000000/9,9999999999/9)*9
```

How does it work?

`1000000000` is the smallest 10 digit number and `9999999999` the biggest 10 digit number. So we devide both by 9 to get a random number that we multiply with 9. Any number multiplied by 9 is devideable by 9.

Comment: Unless OP would be looking for a 10-digit string like where `0000000009` would be the smalles value. I don't think the question is clear enough. With your reasoning `1000000000` is the smalles possible value (which could be true aswell) =)

Comment: @JvdV Well yes, you are right I assumed 10-digit number means no zeros in the beginning. If `0000000009` should be the smallest 10-digit number then `=RANDBETWEEN(1,9999999999/9)*9` would work as formula (assuming a numberformat that forces 10 digits to generate the zeros).

Comment: Yes so maybe, `=TEXT(RANDBETWEEN(1,1111111111)*9,"0000000000")` or indeed a cell format forcing the 0's. Again, my assumption could be wrong, but OP is just too unclear.